# How can I split a string into tokens in C#?

Tags: c#

Can you tell me how to split string for example:

```
string x="2+3-45.3+9"
```

into array

```
['2','+','3','-','45.3','+','9']
```

in C#?

Comment: if it's always mathematical formulas you can use NCalc. It's a free library that does alot a parsing for formulas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with Regex :

```
string x="2+3-45.3+9";
string pattern = @"([+\-*/])";
var tokens = Regex.Split(x, pattern).Where(i => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(i)).ToList();
```

Comment: but i want to have an array with all separated operators and numbers

Comment: well `tokens` is that list, no?

Answer (score 2):

Splitting strings into tokens is complex and cannot be achieved with a few lines of code. You will need to build a Parser to achieve this. More details on the algorithm can be found on this link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser

I would suggest using libraries like ANTLR or simpler ones like RPNParser that has the logic built in to perform parsing and output the tokens

Comment: i want only separate operators and numbers

Comment: In that case, the regex that @Ibiza has shared should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to first define what delimiters you are going to use.
Then you can either do a .Split() on the string you can use regex if you are familiar with that.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(string x, @"regex here"))
```

assuming it is simple, try something like this

```
cha[]r tokenized;
foreach(char c in x)
{
    if(c is number or decimal)
       add to token
    if(c is symbol)
       inc tokenized index and add to tekenized arr
}
```

Comment: `string.Split` wouldn't work here since it does not include the delimiters that you split on.  I assume that's what you mean by "do a .Split() on the string".